# $4$ digit number that the sum of its digits in the $4$th power equal itself

Tags: algorithms

I need to find all the $4$ digit numbers that the sum of every digit in the $4$th power is equal to the $4$ digit number. My first thought was brute forcing it but i was hinted that i can use tables for a faster method. Is there an algorithmic way using tables probably on doing that.

An example is $1634$ =$1^4$+$6^4$+$3^4$+$4^4$

Comment: You can at least use some elementary number theory to reduce the number of possibilities to check. By using Fermat’s Little Theorem for $p=5$, for such a number, the number of digits which are neither 0 nor 5 is congruent to the last digit modulo 5. So, for example, if such a number contains neither 0 nor 5, the last digit is 4 or 9. Moreover, if it contains 9, then all remaining digits are 7 or smaller. Also, at least one digit is greater than 3, as is easily seen via proof by contradiction.

Comment: For numbers less than $9^4 = 6561$, you need not look at any numbers containing a $9$. Similarly for numbers less than $8^4 = 4096$, $7^4 = 2401$, $6^4 = 1296$.

Comment: FYI : https://oeis.org/A005188